# A "1" output with Facebook php-sdk

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

I can't figure it out and it's hard to Google:

My iframe produces a "1" just before the

but I can't figure out why and where it comes from.
http://www.quepasa.in-town.nl/facebook/

My code:

```
require 'fb-sdk/src/facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId' => 'xxxxxxx',
'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
));

$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();

$page_id = $signed_request["page"]["id"];
$page_admin = $signed_request["page"]["admin"];
$like_status = $signed_request["page"]["liked"];
$country = $signed_request["user"]["country"];
$locale = $signed_request["user"]["locale"];

if ($like_status) {
echo include("page-revealed.php");} else {echo include("page-signup.php");}
```

The revealed and signup have not more then this and temporary deleting everything didn't help.

Does anyone know where this is coming from?

Comment: Can you finish the question, you put 'My iFrame produces a "1" just before the ... '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are doing an "echo" on an include. Remove the echo and just have it as

```
if ($like_status) {
include("page-revealed.php");} else { include("page-signup.php");}
```

And you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to echo include, just include basically

Just do:

```
include("http://www.mysite.net/script.php");
```

Or:

```
echo file_get_contents("http://www.mysite.net/script.php");
```